# Can I get the length of the values in a tag

Tags: c#, xelement

I have an XML file that starts with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- This is a simple page with no bean -->
<html lang="en"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
    <title>Combo boxes page</title>
</h:head>
```

What I'm doing in order to work on this file is:

```
XElement root = (XElement.Load(fileName, LoadOptions.SetLineInfo | LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace));
```

Once I have the root, can I get the length of the text in it? (The HTML language...)

Comment: Did you try root.Value.ToString().Length ?

Comment: Is this resolved or are there clarifications/follow up questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want the length of the string starting with the opening html tag (`<html...`) to the closing html tag (`</html>`)?

```
XElement root = (XElement.Load(fileName ,LoadOptions.SetLineInfo | LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace));

int htmlLength = root.ToString().Length;

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("length of string including html tags: " + htmlLength);
```

Or do you want the length of the string between the html tags?

```
String html = root.ToString();
int indexOpeningTag = html.IndexOf(">")+1;
String contentInHtmlTags = html.Substring(indexOpeningTag, html.IndexOf("</html>") - indexOpeningTag);

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("length of string between html tags: " + contentInHtmlTags.Length);
```